# Better way to load data for AutocompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, autocompletetextview

I've got two Activitys in Android. Lets call them A and B. 
Activity A has a ViewPager and its data will be loaded via AsyncTask.
The user can start Activty B from Activity A.

In Activity B I've got an AutocompleteTextView and its content will be loaded with a AsyncTask, too. (The App will only make an request when it is not cached)

My problem is when I search in Activity B, the AutoCompleteTextView will generate too much AsyncTasks and when I leave Activity B it takes a while too load the data for the ViewPager (in Activity A).

I think the App can only handle some of the AsyncTask at the same time. The rest is waiting and when I leave Activity B there are still waiting some AsyncTasks (for AutocomplteTextView)

My question is: How can I improve this. Can I use a Service (with an extra process)

Comment: no `AsyncTask`s needed: just use adapter's built-in filtering mechanism, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) for example

Comment: Thats what I am looking for